# enscript installation - can't find its profile

Tags: enscript

I have just built an installed enscript {1-6-6} from the tarball.  When I try to run it I get:

```
enscript-1.6.6$ bin/enscript -v -Eperl --output=doprint.ps ../doprint.pl
AFM: scanning path...
AFM: reading font map "/home/bercos/bin/enscript-1.6.6/share/enscript/afm/font.map"
enscript: couldn't find prolog "enscript.pro": No such file or directory
states: undefined state `lang_enscript'
```

but when I check:

```
enscript-1.6.6$ find . -name enscript.pro
./share/enscript/enscript.pro
```

All I have done on the system [Debian] is take the tarball, make, make check [all tests passed] and then a make install.  Is there something more that enscript needs?  I added `ENSCRIPT_LIBRARY=/home/bercos/bin/enscript-1.6.6/etc` to my .profile.

Comment: I just backed up to 1.6.5 and get the same problem.  1.6.6 dates from 2012[!] and I'd have thought that there would've been another release if it had a problem.  1.6.5 dates from 20100111.  I wonder if there's some way to figure out where it is looking for its profile.  I've tried -v but that doesn't tell me.

Comment: probably incorrect installation path!.Please see below and let me know. If it didn't work we should check the `ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES` were setup correctly!

Answer (score 0):

According to [enscript man](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-enscript/)
the installation path for `enscript` should as follows:

```
FILES
       /usr/share/enscript/*.hdr               header files
       /usr/share/enscript/*.enc               input encoding vectors
       /usr/share/enscript/enscript.pro        PostScript prolog
       /usr/share/enscript/*.afm               AFM files for PostScript fonts
       /usr/share/enscript/font.map            index for the AFM files
       /usr/share/enscript/enscript.st         states definition file
       /usr/etc/enscript.cfg                   system-wide configuration file
       /usr/etc/enscriptsite.cfg               site configuration file
       ~/.enscriptrc                           personal configuration file
       ~/.enscript/                            personal resource directory
```

The output of the command `find` in your case was as follows:

```
enscript-1.6.6$ find . -name enscript.pro
./share/enscript/enscript.pro
```

The command above indicates that you ran the command `find` inside the `enscript` folder. Usually the output should be:

```
./enscript.pro
```

I would suggest that you do:

```
cd /usr/share/enscript
```

Then run the command

```
ll

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4807 Jun  9  2014 885910.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4805 Jun  9  2014 88591.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4804 Jun  9  2014 88592.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4804 Jun  9  2014 88593.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4804 Jun  9  2014 88594.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4804 Jun  9  2014 88595.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4806 Jun  9  2014 88597.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4805 Jun  9  2014 88599.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2407 Jun  9  2014 a2ps.hdr
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 24  2017 afm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4816 Jun  9  2014 asciidkno.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4804 Jun  9  2014 ascii.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4816 Jun  9  2014 asciifise.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1947 Jun  9  2014 edd.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1868 Jun  9  2014 emacs.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3576 Jun  9  2014 enscript-color.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2763 Jun  9  2014 enscript.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6930 Jun  9  2014 enscript.pro
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  916 Jun  9  2014 frame.hdr
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 24  2017 hl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4800 Jun  9  2014 hp8.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4805 Jun  9  2014 ibmpc.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4802 Jun  9  2014 koi8.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4802 Jun  9  2014 mac.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2469 Jun  9  2014 mp.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  867 Jun  9  2014 ps.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  856 Jun  9  2014 pslatin1.enc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2310 Jun  9  2014 simple.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1325 Jun  9  2014 squeeze.hdr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4799 Jun  9  2014 vms.enc
```

These are `enscript` files that should be in `/usr/share/enscript`

Comment: There's no "/usr/share" -- perhaps there's some problem in the makefile/configure script.  I don't have root privileges, so I'm trying to install enscript in my own bin direcctory.  What I did with the tarball was `./configure --profile=/home/bercos/bin/enscript-1.1.6`.   I get exactly those files when I `ls -l` on /home/bercos/bin/enscript-1.6.6/share/enscript.  Perhaps I need some envrionment variable to point something that doesn't get set by ./configure to point to one of my directories?  I did add "ENSCRIPT_LIBRARY=/home/bercos/bin/enscript-1.6.6/etc" to my environment... are there others

Comment: @BernieC . you have to have root privileges to install it. it has to be installed in the same tree of folders as above let me know ;-)

Comment: Ah.  So I'm just out of luck with enscript {the sysadmins aren't interested in installing it for me}.  Too bad.  In the past I've done OK with using --profile=<localdir> to get a locally installed program, but I guess that doesn't quite work for enscript.  Thanks!